# OutOfMemory when decoding a (small - 30KB) bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

My Android app includes a popup dialog with a scrollable grid of about 80 small buttons. Each button is textured with a bitmap. In the previous version of the app, the PNGs I create those bitmaps from were 144x144 and about 8-15KB in size; everything was fine, I was getting an occasional OutOfMemory crash but I guess everybody gets those sometimes.

In the last release I decided it's 2023 and upped the PNGs size to 256x256 which resulted in the size increase to about 30 KB on average. Now the OutOfMemory crashes immediatelly increased at least 10-fold, most of them on Android 5 and 6, sometimes 7 (5 is the minimum I support). I haven't seen a single crash on anything newer than 7 yet.

The stack trace in Crashlytics looks like this:

```
     Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
     Failed to allocate a 2359308 byte allocation with 1723183 free bytes and 1682KB until OOM
     dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray (VMRuntime.java)
     androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable (AppCompatResources.java:66)
     org.distorted.objects.RubikObject.createStaticIconDrawable (RubikObject.java:143)
```

where the 'RubikObject.java:143' is

```
     mStaticIconD = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(act,mIconID);
```

where 'act' is an Activity, and mIconID is the 30KB PNG. (this is a PNG embedded in the app's resources, I am sure of its size)

How come it's crashing decoding such miniscule PNGs? How come Crashlytics says '2359308 byte allocation' ( 2.3MB ) ? What 2.3MB?

Maybe 2.3 MB comes from 80x 30 KB?

Testing with a Memory Profiler on an Emulator and 2 real devices ( granted, much newer than Android 5 or 6) does not reveal any obvious memory leaks. Anyway, there was no problem before with 144x144 PNGs.

Comment: I dont know. But why this bitmap list ?. Just grab them from drawable everytime. Its 2023 ;-).

Comment: `30KB bitmap. (this is a bitmap embedded in the app's resources` You will not have bitmaps in your drawable resource i think but png or jpg files.

Comment: yes, those are PNGs. Eighty 256x256, about 25-35 KB in size, PNGs.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'drab them from drawable' ?

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you mean. There's no permanent bitmap list. I create those 80 bitmaps anew every time people open up the popup dialog.

Comment: No. You will never make a bitmap list. Make an integer list with resource id's. And grab from drawable when needed. Well if possible. I dont know what you do and if this is possible.

Comment: Also note that the size of the PNG != the size of the bitmap. The PNG will be compressed to some degree, so the bitmap in memory will be larger. If you are using 32-bits per pixel (aka 4-bytes), then 80 144x144 bitmaps is 6480 KB. Increasing the size to 256x256 and you have 20480 KB (20 MB).

Comment: 2359308 bytes is not _exactly_ the size of a 256x256 bitmap with 4-byte color (that's 2097152 bytes), but it's close-_ish_...I'd guess that's related, though I can't explain what the difference would be (the details of memory allocation are not my specialty).

Comment: Ultimately, loading a bunch of bitmaps into memory without crashing is sometimes more art than science (I've had to do this; the experience was intentionally far more basic on older devices due to those limitations). Depending on what these textures are, maybe consider using smaller ones on lower density devices or... heck, you said it's not crashing on newer APIs, just make that the cutoff.  Both are pretty easy with resource qualifiers.

Comment: I have actually managed to work around the problem. Turns out that if you keep the PNG in 'drawable' directory, the system upscales it when it reads it into memory! This is why a 256x256, 30KB PNGs became 1MB large each. 80 of them and we had 80 MB of heap taken = often a crash on Android<=7 (Androids>=8 keep pixel data in native memory!). Solution: move everything to 'drawable-nodpi' and lower 256x256 to 192x192 => each 1MB large Bitmap became 150KB. No crashes now!